# Algorithm for testing a sequence for convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have this exam problem which states the following:

A sequence of real numbers ${\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty}$ is given with $x_1=1$, $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{20+x_n}$, $n \geq 1$. Test for convergence of this sequence, and if it is convergent evaluate its limit.

So after evaluating a few values of $x_n$, I realized that the sequence is increasing and that its bounded from above with $5$. What implies that the sequence is converging(by the Monotone Convergence Theorem).

My question is, what would be the algorithmic way to solve this and to prove it properly ? How should the limit be evaluated in this case later on?

Also, would we say for such stated sequence that it is given recursively ?

Comment: Try a proof by induction

Comment: Do you know the Banach fixed point theorem?

Comment: @zhw. No, I am not familiar with that

Comment: @lhf I managed to prove by induction that the sequence is increasing. Thanks. How should I prove that it is bounded ? And that it converges to a limit later on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking up from where you left off in the comment:
Suppose x_n (defined above) is monotonically increasing.

The upper bound case is easy to show!
$$x_1=1<21$$
Suppose $x_k < 21$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $x_{k+1} = \sqrt{20 + x_{k}} \leq \sqrt{41} \lt 21$, hence we have shown $x_n \lt 21$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

By the monotone convergence theorem, there is a limit. Find it now:

Remember that $\lim s_{n+1} = \lim s_{n}$.

Then $\lim x_{n+1} = \lim x_n$ satisfies $ x = \sqrt{20 + x}$ for a grand result of $x=5$. ($x$ here is the limit of the $x_n$ sequence)

As a whole, the process here is to show the monotonic increasing-ness of the sequence, use induction to show an upper bound with some constant substitution, and then use a recursive algebra trick to understand the limit's actual form.

I hope this supports your exam prep.

Comment: This is nice, many thanks. How did you compute the limit here? I knew it was $5$, but I didn’t know how to prove it, and that particular part in your answer isn’t clear to me(I understand $\lim x_{n+1} = \lim x_n$, the rest is where I get stuck)

Comment: Absolutely! 
There’s a neat algebra trick involving recursive formulas that reveals the solution. 

Suppose we want to evaluate $\sqrt(20+\sqrt(20+...))$. If we know that the above expression converges, we know it converges to a value, which we call x. Then we have $x=\sqrt(20+\sqrt(20+...))$. A reflection will let you realize that since this is an infinite radical that repeats itself, x is also the part that is repeated. So we wind up at $x=\sqrt(20+x)$. Can you see that we substituted x for the part that was repeated?

Comment: Alright I just remembered that trick, I see that we subsitutetd $x$ for the part that was repeated. But how did you come up with $5$ then ?

Comment: You can solve the algebra trick: $x=\sqrt(20+x) <=> x^2-x-20=0 <=> (x-5)(x+4)=0$, and negative 4 doesn't work in this context. Does that help?

Comment: That’s it! Thanks man

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks! I'm glad to have helped. Do well on your exam! :)