# Finding the limit of a sequence that is convergent involving square roots

Tags: real-analysis

Let $s_1 = \sqrt{6}$, $s_2 = \sqrt{6 +\sqrt{ 6 }}$, $s_3 = \sqrt{6 + \sqrt{6 +\sqrt {6} }}$, and in general define $s_{n + 1}= \sqrt{6 + s_n}$ . Prove that $(s_n)$ converges, and find its limit.

I know that the first part can be proved by theorem because our sequence $s_n$ is monotone increasing, but $s_n$ is bounded by induction if we choose an appropriate k in real numbers.
However, how does one find its limit.

Comment: Solve $s^2=s+6$, $s\gt0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Algorithm for testing a sequence for convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806363/algorithm-for-testing-a-sequence-for-convergence)

Welcome to MSE, and I recently answered a similar question here.

From the stage that we know a limit exists, we can recognize that since $\lim_{n->\infty}s_{n+1}=\lim_{n->\infty}s_n$, $\lim_{n->\infty}s_n$ satisfies $s = \sqrt{6+s}$. From that, we get $s^2=6+s$, as J.W.Tanner suggested in his comment. We solve for the limit with a solution to this quadratic.

I hope this helps in your studies :)

Comment: Hahaha, I think this helps quite a bit

Answer (score 0):

As you point out, the limit exists since $s_{n+1}>s_n$ and $s_n<3$. The first claim is apparent and the second follows by induction, since if $s_n<3$ then $s_{n+1}=\sqrt{6+s_n}<\sqrt{6+3}=3$.

Now that we know the limit exists, let $L$ denotes its value. Then necessarily $L=\sqrt{6+L}$, from which we see that $L\geq 0$ and also $L^2=6+L$. Thus $(L-3)(L+2)=0$ and so $L=3$.